# Setting access token to cookie in Spring Security OAuth2

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I would like to write OAuth2 access token to a cookie instead of writing to response. Since my OAuth request uses `/oauth/token` endpoint defined in `TokenEndpoint.java` of Spring Security OAuth2 module, the token is always written to response.

How can I remove this token from response and set to cookie? Should I implement my own `TokenEndpoint`?

Comment: That is a Spring provided class. It is the default class which accepts the oauth/token requests and constructs the response. It writes to Response body. I need to write this token to a cookie instead of response.

Comment: According to me you have to provide custom imeplementation to achieve your requirement.

As you are using OAuth means your server is provider for multiple client(s) that might be browser, mobile app etc so cookie will not work for every client.

Comment: @Athomas Why do you need the access token in cookie? A cookie is bind to a host, hence you can't send the cookie to another host. Moreover, you can't read the cookie with JavaScript to get the access token.

Comment: I don't want to send the cookie to another domain. Just want to send the token my backend without setting in the request everytime

Comment: @Athomas If you send the token to your backend, you can't read that token out-of-the-box, because Spring Security OAuth2 doesn't support it. You have also write your own resource server filter implementation. That's a lot of work for nothing. Why do you want to use cookies?

Comment: @Athomas Did you find the answer?If so I want to do the same.Help me with that

Comment: @ammy, no I did not end up writing a cookie, instead I implemented my use case with token written to the response itself,